# Which are the main funding routes for university research in chemistry in Switzerland?

Tags: funding, university, chemistry, switzerland

I was wondering where university group leaders in Switzerland obtain funding from other than the Swiss National Science Foundation now that ERC grants are out of reach for this country.

Comment: Seems to be (1) collaborate with institutions in the EU, and (2) wait for the promised replacement funding mechanisms.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, from what i see in the SNSF website they already have replacement funding mechanisms in place such as SNSF starting grant (ERC equivalent). Was just wondering about other sources other than the SNSF. Industrial funding would probably be one, but maybe there are other organizations similar to the SNSF. For instance in UK there is EPSRC but also the royal society.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, I was mainly focusing on the ERC grants. One could, of course, petition the government to comply with the EU conditions, restoring ERC eligibility...